# How can I place multiple inset text boxes within the viewport produced with Show

Tags: plotting, graphics, text, inset

I'd like to ultimately have 3 inset boxes for information of 3 different lines on my graph. In order to minimalise the example I've just attempted 2 here, but the result is the same, that only the first box (in the top right) appears. Could anyone help me with this and identify what needs changing?

**Code:**

```
  Show[Plot[fit[x], {x, 0, 800}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotStyle -> Red, Axes -> False, 
  Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Time /s", 
    "Counts Recorded in the Previous 15 seconds"}, 
  ImageSize -> Large], 
 Plot[fit2[x], {x, 0, 800}, PlotRange -> All, PlotTheme -> "Detailed",
   PlotStyle -> Green, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> Large], 
 Plot[fit3[x], {x, 0, 800}, PlotRange -> All, PlotTheme -> "Detailed",
   PlotStyle -> Purple, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> Large], 
 ListPlot[dataHist5, ImageSize -> Large],
 Graphics[
  Inset[Framed[
    Column[{Style["Run 0", Bold], 
      Row[{"Text1"}], 
      Row[{"Text2"}], 
      Row[{"Text3"}], 
      Row[{"Text4"}], 
      Row[{"Text5"}]}], 
    Background -> White, RoundingRadius -> 5], {Right, Top}, 
   Scaled[{1.1, 1.2}]], 
  Inset[Framed[
    Column[{Style["Run 1", Bold], 
      Row[{"Text6"}], 
      Row[{"Text7"}], 
      Row[{"Text8"}], 
      Row[{"Text9"}], 
      Row[{"Text10"}]}], 
    Background -> White, RoundingRadius -> 5], {Left, Top}, 
   Scaled[{1.1, 1.2}]]], 
 PlotLabel -> 
  Style["Effects of Uncertainty Weightings - Run 0", Bold, 
   Black]]
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Bonus Question:**

Does anyone know how to put a single element of the legend in an inset box? So it just shows a Red Line, followed by fit[x], for example on one of the rows?

Comment: Have you tried using `Epilog`.

Comment: No, I'm not so well versed in mathematica. That graph alone is well over a week's work in the making for me. Would you mind showing me how Epilog could reproduce a similar result?

Comment: Can you explain the "Bonus Question" in more detail? Not sure what you mean by "on one of the rows"?

Comment: Just put `Inset`s in `Graphics` in braces: `Graphics[{Inset[...],Inset[...]}]` and adjust the position of the second inset?

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi Essentially, in the textbox insets - I'd quite like it that in one of the rows, which currently reads 'text 6' for example, it was one one element of the legend, say a red line, with fit (x) next to it, as appears next to the plot when the code is run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When positioning multiple insets, I have found it useful to use the plot's coordinate system to indicate where in the plot I want some corner of the text box to be placed. I indicate the corner with `Scaled`. To demonstrate this technique, I will use the data and fit from a previous question of yours.

```
dataHist5 =
  {{Around[16.5, 1.5], Around[77.8, 8.8]}, 
   {Around[34.5, 1.5], Around[60.5, 8.0]},
   {Around[52.5, 1.5], Around[63.8, 8.0]}, 
   {Around[106.5, 1.5], Around[42.4, 6.5]},
   {Around[124.5, 1.5], Around[41.7, 6.5]}, 
   {Around[142.5, 1.5], Around[14.6, 3.8]},
   {Around[160.5, 1.5], Around[33.9, 5.8]}, 
   {Around[178.5, 1.5], Around[29.4, 5.4]},
   {Around[196.5, 1.5], Around[33.5, 5.8]}, 
   {Around[214.5, 1.5], Around[30.9, 5.6]},
   {Around[232.5, 1.5], Around[31.1, 5.8]}, 
   {Around[250.5, 1.5], Around[21.5, 4.6]},
   {Around[268.5, 1.5], Around[4.3, 2.1]}, 
   {Around[286.5, 1.5], Around[6.4, 2.5]},
   {Around[322.5, 1.5], Around[7.5, 2.7]}, 
   {Around[340.5, 1.5], Around[4.5, 2.1]},
   {Around[358.5, 1.5], Around[11., 3.3]}, 
   {Around[376.5, 1.5], Around[14.0, 3.7]},
   {Around[394.5, 1.5], Around[14.0, 3.7]}, 
   {Around[466.5, 1.5], Around[0.6, 0.7]},
   {Around[502.5, 1.5], Around[2.2, 1.5]}, 
   {Around[520.5, 1.5], Around[9.4, 3.1]},
   {Around[538.5, 1.5], Around[4.1, 2.0]}, 
   {Around[646.5, 1.5], Around[2.2, 1.5]},
   {Around[682.5, 1.5], Around[0.6, 0.7]}};
fitData = {#[[1, 1]], #[[2, 1]]} & /@ dataHist5;

Clear[A, k]
uncertainties = dataHist5[[All, 2, 2]];
fit =
  NonlinearModelFit[fitData, A Exp[-k t], {A, k}, t, Weights -> 1/uncertainties^2]

{A, k} = {A, k} /. fit["BestFitParameters"];
{σA, σk} = fit["ParameterErrors"];
hLife = Log[2]/Around[k, σk];
seA = Around[A, σA];
halfLife = hLife[[1]];
sehalfLife = hLife[[2]];

Show[
  Plot[fit[x], {x, 0, 800},
    PlotRange -> All,
    PlotTheme -> "Detailed",
    PlotStyle -> Red,
    Axes -> False,
    Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
    FrameLabel -> {"Time /s", "Counts Recorded in the Previous 15 seconds"},
    ImageSize -> Large],
  ListPlot[dataHist5, ImageSize -> Large],
  Graphics[
    {Inset[
       Framed[
         Column[
           {Style["Run 0", Bold],
            Row[{"Text1"}],
            Row[{"Text2"}],
            Row[{"Text3"}],
            Row[{"Text4"}],
            Row[{"Text5"}]}],
         Background -> White,
         RoundingRadius -> 5],
       {800, 30},
       Scaled[{1, 1}]],
     Inset[
       Framed[
         Column[
           {Style["Run 0", Bold],
            Row[{"Text1"}],
            Row[{"Text2"}],
            Row[{"Text3"}],
            Row[{"Text4"}],
            Row[{"Text5"}]}],
         Background -> White,
         RoundingRadius -> 5],
       {800, 58},
       Scaled[{1, 1}]],
     Inset[
       Framed[
         Column[
           {Style["Run 0", Bold],
            Row[{"N=" , Length[dataHist5], "/50"}],
            Row[{"A=" , seA}],
            Row[{Subscript[t, 1/2], "=", PlusMinus[halfLife, sehalfLife]}], 
            Row[{"χ^{2}=" , fit["ANOVATableSumsOfSquares"][[2]]}], 
            Row[{"Reduced χ^{2}=", fit["ANOVATableMeanSquares"][[2]]}]}],
         Background -> White,
         RoundingRadius -> 5],
       {800, 90},
       Scaled[{1, 1}]]}],
  PlotLabel -> 
    Row[{"Decay Curve of Phosphorus-31 by ", Superscript[β, "+"], " Emission"}]]
```

[image: plot]

This technique is advantageous when you want to line up the text boxes with one edge of the plot, which is often the case.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html)

```
epilog = {
   Inset[Framed[
     Column[{Style["Run 0", Bold], Row[{"Text1"}], 
       Row[{"Text2"}], Row[{"Text3"}], Row[{"Text4"}], 
       Row[{"Text5"}]}], Background -> White, RoundingRadius -> 5], 
    Scaled[{0, 1}], ImageScaled[{0, 1}]], 
   Inset[Framed[
     Column[{Style["Run 1", Bold], Row[{"Text6"}], Row[{"Text7"}], 
       Row[{"Text8"}], Row[{"Text9"}], Row[{"Text10"}]}], 
     Background -> White, RoundingRadius -> 5], Scaled[{1, 1}], 
    ImageScaled[{1, 1}]]};

Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, Epilog -> epilog]
```

[image]